# sql could not drop constraint when there is no constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to alter my table and drop a column which i know there is no data in it(because I just created it) now I want to delete it and it says

> "SQL Error (3727): Could not drop constraint. See previous errors."

I use the following code:

```
    ALTER TABLE Object DROP WAddress
```

Comment: See previous errors.

Comment: Is that column linked to some different table

Comment: there is no previous error @NEER

Comment: no it's not linked to any thing @RohanKawade

Comment: Try ALTER TABLE Object DROP COLUMN  WAddress? In other words, aren't you missing the "COLUMN" keyword?

Comment: it worked @SuaveIncompetence post it as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: No worries, that's a very useless error message. It was only that I knew you needed the column keyword in MSSQL when altering or dropping a column, but not when adding a column (just to be inconsistent).

Comment: It seems that the column you're trying to drop probably is being used by some constraint(s). first, you may want to drop the constraint. then drop the column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query is missing the "COLUMN" keyword. Use:

```
ALTER TABLE Object DROP COLUMN WAddress
```

The reason it was throwing the error about the constraint, is that it was expecting that WAddress was the name of a constraint on the table because the keyword "COLUMN" was missing.

Answer (score 2):

Below are the syntax to drop column(s) from table:


Drop single column:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN column_name;
```

Drop multiple columns for SQL Server:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN (column_name1, column_name2);
```

For Oracle:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP (column_name1, column_name2);
```

In your case you want to drop a `single column` so `COLUMN` keyword `is required` after `DROP`.

 If you want to drop multiple columns, you can omit `COLUMN` keyword based on DB that you are using.

Comment: I think for multiple columns, your syntax won't work. It should be

ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN column_name1, column_name2;

Comment: PratikPatel is right, try:
CREATE TABLE #Object
(
 [a]   INTEGER
 ,[b]  INTEGER
 ,[c]  INTEGER
)
ALTER TABLE [#Object]
DROP COLUMN a,b